# Telerik RadComboBox filter with multiple words separated with blank space

Tags: filter, telerik, radcombobox

i'm wondering if there is a way for a telerik radcombobox (or radautocompletebox or asp dropdownlist maybe) to filter two or more words. For example : if this radcombobox has a value like "A long road" i would like to type inside radcombobox "a road" and I would like to get the value "A long road". Unfortunately, the Filter="Contains" is filtering only one word. Additionally, i've read that this is achieved by ItemsRequested or by a web service. I would like to know if someone knows about this issue and if there is any example for these two ways to achieve that (or maybe another more simple way).
Thnx